# Works locally but not online

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have it so when you click on the elements such as the top right one hydrogen it plays a video in the big center div and displays info about hydrogen. I got it to work locally but i am unable to get it to work online.
Please any help would be great.

Here is the link to my project
http://travismichael.net/periodic_elements/

Here is the script for my site

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {


$('div.video').hide();

$('.icon').click(function(){
    var id=$(this).data('id'),
        thisDiv=$("div.video[data-id='" + id +"']"),
        thisVideo=$("div.video[data-id='" + id +"']").find('video');

    $('video').each(function() {
        this.pause();
        this.currentTime = 0;
    });

       $('div.video').not(thisDiv).fadeOut('fast');

       thisDiv.fadeIn();      
       thisVideo.get(0).play();   
    });

});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#periodictable td").hover(function() {
      $(this).stop().animate({opacity: "1"}, 'fast');
    },
    function() {
      $(this).stop().animate({opacity: ".7"}, 'slow');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What error do you get in your console?

Comment: `$('video').each` is throwing `Uncaught Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11`

Answer (score 1):

**Error is here:**

You're trying with

```
var thisDiv = ("div.video[data-id='" + id +"']");// but it returns jQuery object, 
                                                 // not element

// Thats why below statement will not work
// because it works on element

alert(thisDiv.nodeType);
```

So you should try like this:

```
var thisDiv = ("div.video[data-id='" + id +"']")[0]; // returns the element
alert(thisDiv.nodeType); // and then get the nodeType
```

Answer (score 0):

When checked I get an error message that says the Element is undefined.

you should past the error your console is giving you, as it is going to give much more explanation to what you are looking for.

It is obviously throwing an exception and whatever your exception is is displaying the error message, so...you try it on your local host where the files are defined. Are they declared in your code with a pointer or something to say go look back here and use this when the button is clicked?

It looks like your function should contain these declarations, or you could make them global, not really sure without more info...

Comment: I got it to work locally using MAMP as well as using coda's preview mode(which im pretty sure uses safari webmx). It just wont work when i try to open it online.